# Run time error 91 on a loop - can't see any reason for it

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably something quite obvious, but I have done quite a bit of googling to no avail.

First of all I am more than happy if you have a more succinct way of doing this, I am always keen to learn - this is the best way I could think of to achieve the task.

Basically, once the columns are found I will be transferring data from another sheet that will go at the end of Range(xlDown) and offset by 1 etc.

But at the moment, if i run this as For 1 to 6 it works fine, if I run for 1 to 7 it gives the error but everything is defined in the same way. strSoS is defined, but rngSoS always shows as 'Nothing' even though the other cells work fine?

Columns 1 to 7 have the 7 titles (as stated) in the list of String declarations, the reason it is done this way is that the sheet data will be coming from may have extra columns that wont be required.

Hope you can help solve my issue!

```
Sub ColumnSearch()

Dim strDoN, strOffice, strARN, strPIN, strAN, strAT, strSoS As String
Dim rngDoN, rngOffice, rngARN, rngPIN, rngAN, rngAT, rngSoS As Range

Dim myRange As Range
Dim NumCols, i As Integer

strDoN = "Date of Notification"
strOffice = "Office Centre"
strARN = "Appeal Reference Number"
strPIN = "PIN"
strAN = "Appellant Name"
strAT = "Appeal Type"
strSoS = "SoS Decision Date"



For i = 1 To 7
    If Cells(1, i).Value = strDoN Then
        rngDoN = Cells(1, i).Address(False, False)
    ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = strOffice Then
        rngOffice = Cells(1, i).Address(False, False)
    ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = strARN Then
        rngARN = Cells(1, i).Address(False, False)
    ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = strPIN Then
        rngPIN = Cells(1, i).Address(False, False)
    ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = strAN Then
        rngAN = Cells(1, i).Address(False, False)
    ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = strAT Then
        rngAT = Cells(1, i).Address(False, False)
    ElseIf Cells(1, i).Value = strSoS Then
        rngSoS = Cells(1, i).Address(False, False)

    End If

Next i

MsgBox rngDoN & rngOffice & rngARN & rngPIN & rngAN & rngAT & rngSoS

End Sub
```

Comment: A [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) would be a better fit.

Comment: Are you trying to write the actual cell addresses in undefined ranges? Or are you trying to define those ranges to those addresses? If the latter, use the keyword `Set` in order to define an object variable (such as a range).

Comment: Also, your variable declaration lines are incorrect.  Take a look here at the section `Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement` http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx

Comment: It works till the last because that is the only one that is declared as a range.  The others are all declared as variants.  And you need to set ranges `Set rngSoS = Cells(1, i)` no address.  If you want to declare all as ranges then use `Dim rngDoN as range, rngARN as range,...` and use the set on all.

Comment: @tigeravatar thank you very much, I absolutely was not aware of that (I am selftaught in VBA and have picked up some bad habits it would seem!). Also thank you Scott for clarifying :)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to stuff a string address (text) into an unassigned [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

```
Dim strDoN, strOffice As String, strARN As String, strPIN As String
Dim strAN As String, strAT As String, strSoS As String
Dim rngDoN As Range, rngOffice As Range, rngARN As Range
Dim rngPIN As Range, rngAN As Range, rngAT As Range, rngSoS As Range

For i = 1 To 7
    Select Case Cells(1, i).Value
        Case strDoN
            Set rngDoN = Cells(1, i)   '<~~ set the range object to this cell
        Case strOffice
            Set rngOffice = Cells(1, i)
        Case strARN
            Set rngARN = Cells(1, i)
        Case strPIN
            Set rngPIN = Cells(1, i)
        Case strAN
            Set rngAN = Cells(1, i)
        Case strAT
            Set rngAT = Cells(1, i)
        Case strSoS
            Set rngSoS = Cells(1, i)
        Case Else
            'no match - do nothing
    End Select
Next i

MsgBox rngDoN.Address(0, 0) & Chr(9) & rngOffice.Address(0, 0) & Chr(9) & _
       rngARN.Address(0, 0) & Chr(9) & rngPIN.Address(0, 0) & Chr(9) & _
       rngAN.Address(0, 0) & Chr(9) & rngAT.Address(0, 0) & Chr(9) & _
       rngSoS.Address(0, 0)
```

Your narrative is a little short on what you actually want to accomplish. I've set the range objects to the matching cells and returned their addresses to the message box.

The `rngSoS` was failing because it is the only one actually declared as a range-type variable.

Comment: That makes perfect sense actually, I didn't think that what I was returning wasn't neccessarily a range. Ahh I'm new here and enter posted this rather than giving me a line break!

What I am doing is identifying which columns exist before I attempt to copy any data across, previously in my rather crude solution I simply copied Range(Ax:Kx) and pasted from one sheet to another.

So my plan now is to only copy data across if the columns exist on both sheets and this was the way I was going about doing that (and finding the correct Address to paste the values to)